# Adding a 'published_at' field to a Post model that has a 'published' boolean field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

My Post model has a boolean called "published":

*schema.rb:**

```
  create_table "posts", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "content"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",                            :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                            :null => false
    t.boolean  "published",          :default => false
  end
```

If it is true, the post is considered published, and it appears in the published section of the user's profile, and if it is false it appears in the draft section (sorry, but I'm not sure how to deal with the code duplication).

**posts_controller.rb:**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:show, :index]

  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end
```

etc...

**users_controller.rb:**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @posts = @user.posts
  end
```

etc...

**_shared/posts.thml:**

```
   <h2>Published</h2>
    <% @posts.each do |post| %>
      <% if post.published? %>
        <div id="post-<%= post.id %>" class="post">
          <%= image_tag post.image.url(:medium) %>
          <h2 class="post-title"><%= link_to post.title, post %></h2>
          <%= link_to post.user.email, post.user %>
          <p><%= post.content %></p>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>

    <h2>Draft</h2>
    <% @posts.each do |post| %>
      <% if not post.published? %>
        <div id="post-<%= post.id %>" class="post">
          <%= image_tag post.image.url(:medium) %>
          <h2 class="post-title"><%= link_to post.title, post %></h2>
          <%= link_to post.user.email, post.user %>
          <p><%= post.content %></p>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

Example:

**users.html.erb:**

```
<h2>User Show</h2>
<%= image_tag @user.avatar.url(:medium) %>
<span>Email: <%= @user.email %></span><br />
<span>ID: <%= @user.id %></span><br />

<%= render 'shared/posts' %>
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<%= render 'shared/posts' %>
```

(I know the views are a little bit messy. I think later on I will just show a text saying 'draft' beside each post draft).

The problem is that the posts will be sorted by their `created_at` date. I want them to be sorted by a `published_at` date in the post's index page (I think that makes more sense) .

**I know how to add the `published_at` `t.datetime` field via migration. But I'm not sure what code to use for the logic in the `published_at` field.**

Any suggestions?

(by the way, what sounds more correct? '`published_at`' or '`published_on`'?)

Comment: @mu is too short Updated my answer.

Comment: @mu is too short Sorry, OK, added the controllers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add in your table `published_at` (datetime) field. and when you publish then update the published_at field and then when you fetch data use `order('published_at Desc')`

```
@posts =  @users.posts.order('published_at DESC')
```

logic like in your controller

```
if params[:post][:published] == true # whatever you got in controller rather than params[:post][:published]
   @post.published_at = Time.now
else
  @post.published_at = ""
end
```

that means, when `published` value is true then above code perform in your controller and in your published_at field add value Time.now and if value of published is false then above code is not perform so `published_at` field have blank value.

or, by using model like

```
before_save :published_post

def published_post
  if self.published == true
   self.published_at = Time.now
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but, that's precisely what I don't know how to do: the logic to update the `published_at` date.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try it out. Just one question: why in the controller and not in the model as a callback?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a beginner. can you give me some hint of how to do it as a callback?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to adjust your controller:

```
def show
  @user      = User.find(params[:id])
  posts      = @user.posts.order('published_at').group_by(&:published)
  @published = posts[true]
  @drafts    = posts[false]
end
```

Then you can use `@published` and `@drafts` to produce your lists. If you want the most recently published ones first then:

```
posts = @user.posts.order('published_at desc').group_by(&:published)
```

Comment: You can let the database deal with that. Your Post model should figure out that there is a `published_at` all by itself.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a callback to the model? Like telling Rails: when `published` changes to true update `published` with the current date?

Comment: Oh, I didn't see anything about that in your question. I'd drop the `published` boolean, add a `def published? !published_at.nil? end` method to `Post`, and then set the `published_at` date to indicate that the `Post` has been published.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a Rails beginner. Can you give me an example of the code? (but without the `published` boolean, how are users going to mark a post as draft?)